# Issue with referencing in Overleaf

Tags: bibtex

I am trying to reference using bibtex in Overleaf and I keep getting [?], I have tried all that I can but still not working.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: show your log, you presumaby have an error that is preventing tex reaching the bibliography so that latxmk (overleaf) calls bibtex. But if you do not show any code or any error message, no one will be able to help